# Why is meteor loading external resources slowly?

Tags: html, meteor, meteor-blaze

I've been working on a Meteor web application the past few months and I noticed that when I open a page with some pictures it loads the html and the css instantly, but the pictures are rendered slower.

I store the urls in my mongo db and I pull out the content from my /public folder as normal. The funny thing is that I experience the same problem when I fetch some data which should be pre-populated in input fields.The input field is visible the moment I open the page, but the data is passed 1,2 seconds after. Is that a common issue or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Have you looked at the network tab to see what is taking time to load?